# Open file from vifm in split view

Tags: file

I use `vifm` in split mode - it always shows two vertically separated windows each with a directory listing. From there I can open files using the right arrow. However when I open a text file, `vifm` goes to the background and `vi` is in the foreground covering the whole screen. Is it possible to have `vi` only open in the window from where I open the text file (ie. half the screen), and have the other window (the other half of the screen) continue to show `vifm` and the directory listing?

I'm using debian 11 if that matters.

Comment: I’m almost certain this doesn’t belong here and was migrated erroneously, unless you’re using the vifm plugin for vim

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yeah i didn't migrate it here. no i'm not using a vifm plugin for vim - just vifm from the command line

Comment: @Quasímodo [ok done](https://powerusers.codidact.com/posts/284714)